# unicode-math and various fonts fail at giving decent spacing in formula

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

I want to check if this problem is due to my configuration or if it is some kind of bug.

This are the packages I load and the configuration for them (all very minimal in order to test the problem). I'm usin XeTeX 0.9998.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathtools} 
\usepackage{mathcomp,mathrsfs,xfrac,bbm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

When I was writing I kind of noticed that something was strange with spacing in mathematical formulas, then I wrote this
[image: XITS Math]
which is quite terrible. The spacing is not good at all, there are a lot of clashes. Then I tried with some other fonts, choosing among the one supported by unicode-math (found the list in the README), it turns out that I have the same effect with STIX Math and with Latin Modern Math, as you can see
[image: Latin Modern Math]

Here the problem is less evident because, the font is lighter, but confront with the standard version of Latin Modern (without using opentype fonts and unicode-math)

[image: Latin Modern correct]
This is correct, so I thought it was something related to unicode-math, but using Neo Euler and Asana Math it looks OK

[image: Neo Euler]
[image: Asana Math]

Does anybody have a clue of what might be the cause of this problem? Maybe the fonts? I hope not because I'd really like to use XITS or STIX... Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: It is most likely the problem with xelatex. Try lualatex, which is much better at Unicode math right now. Also update to tl2012. The xelatex in tl2012 has some noticeable improvement

Comment: The version I'm using is the latest one! Anyway I'll try with Lualatex too

Comment: OK I tried with lualatex and it's OK, I'll guess I'll stick with it for the moment, even though I prefer XeTeX...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that XeTeX is not applying math italic correction:

- XITS has italic correction and needs it for proper spacing.
- In case of Latin Modern the font does bot provide italic correction at all.
- Asana math lacks italic correction as well, but the glyphs are spaced in a way that alleviates the need of italic correction.
- Euler, though have italic correction, its upright design makes lack of italic correction not very visible (though your example is wrong, you have to pass `math-style=upright` option for Euler alphabets to be used).

Why XeTeX stopped applying italic correction is unclear to me, that part of the code have not been touched for ages, but the code was flawed anyway so my guess is that it worked accidentally and some of the recent math cleanup broke.

However, there is a workaround: open the XITS font in a font editor (preferably FontForge) and set the width of space glyph to **0**, this will cause the engine to apply italic correction again.

*For the curious, the application of italic correction or not depends on whether the space factor of the font is zero, even in the OpenType math branch of the code, and though this is true for TFM math fonts, it is not essentially the case for OpenType font.*

*Also, OpenType math spec diverges from TeX algorithm on when italic correction should be applied, but it is very vague, and MS implementation seems to differ from what is actually documented, so it is not very well supported by XeTeX and LuaTeX yet.*

***Update**: XeTeX's master branch handles this better now, until a more robust handling of italic correction is devised.*

Comment: I'm not a specialist in modifying fonts, but I tried and I think I succeded in make the width of space glyph 0 because in libreoffice i have no space, BUT this workaround didn't solve the problem.... I realy wanted to use XITS though

Comment: Are you sure XeTeX is loading the modified font, how did you install it?

Comment: @KhaledHosny I copied in my /.fonts diretory in my home (I use ubuntu), I can see use it from other softwares (Libre Office for example

Comment: If the other version is in the font path (e.g. if you added texlive font directories to your fontconfig configuration), either can be picked randomly (by XeTeX at least), so you should make sure only the modified font is accessible to XeTeX.

Comment: I tried saving the font with a different name and it doesn't help... I have correcyly space widht=0 on libre office but doesn't help solving my problem...

Anyway I solved switching to lualatex for the moment...

Comment: Try putting the modified font in the current directory where you run xetex and call the font by file name (e.g. `\setmathfont{new_xits-math.otf}`).

Comment: I tried this way too and it doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: @justmyfault: I just tried again with both 0.9998 and the upcoming 0.9999 and it works fine with the new font.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you so much,but I really can't reproduce the solution... you could send me your modified font maybe... but don't bother too much I'm just compiling with lualatex...

Comment: @justmyfault: OK. If you still need the modified font, drop me a line and I’ll send it to you.

Comment: Does anyone know when this fix will make it into an update that can be installed with TeX Live Utility / manager (depends on platform, I think)?